# How to word wrap text in annotation subtitle

Tags: iphone, word-wrap, mkannotationview, subtitle

I tried to insert return and newline chars into the subtitle string, but they ended up as "spaces" and not line breaks. Since subtitle is simply an NSString I must look at the container, which likely means I'll have to roll my own annotation views.

The NSString do become f.ex. "90510\nHollywood, CA", but maybe I have to 'encode' the newlines instead, or use a subclass of NSString to send to subtitle?

What baffles me is that surely, subtitle should be able to "be wrappable", as the MKAnnotation(view) handles too long text by resizing the bubble and adding "...", et cetera.

I do need proper word wrap (and not hard line breaks) for a paragraph of text I'm adding later, but I could possibly do that as a separate alert or modal box type, if you know which ones support word wrap I'd be grateful if you could suggest them.

A hunch is that something could be possible by adding a UILabel as a subview, or somehow access the UILabel(?) that is used to display the subtitle, and set its numberOfLines to 0, but I don't know how to do the latter.

Comment: Seems definite that the callout does not support multiline titles and subtitles. I made a label as subview, appearing when the callout does.  I'll check if the left/right buttons can be made labels instead, to put the text inside the callout bubble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK it can't be done. Setting left/right button text is space-limited indeed. Seems the only solution is to addObserver and roll your own animated views entirely.